# Jenkins multibranch: error MC1000: Unknown build error

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, jenkins-pipeline

Currently, I have a Jenkins multibranch pipeline. It clones my git repo and builds the solution via a Jenkinsfile. The Jenkinsfile has 5 stages:

1. checkout scm
2. restore nugets (using nuget.exe)
3. Build Debug config of solution using msbuild from command line:
   --> bat "\"${tool 'VS2017'}\"\MsBuild.exe %WORKSPACE%\mysolution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=\"x64\""
4. Build Release config of solution using msbuild from command line (same cmd line as above)
5. Build Custom config of solution using msbuild from command line  (same cmd line as above)

So right now this does three builds back to back using MSBuild. Intermittently, one of the the builds fail. The error I get: 
(MarkupCompilePass1 target) -> 
  C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.WinFx.targets(268,9): error MC1000: Unknown build error, 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Not sure why this happens. But as mentioned it only happens sometimes. Other times the build passes successfully. I have a feeling this has to do with an update as this never hapened before. Either with the MSBuild (VS 2017) or a Windows Update (Server 2016).

Any help on this greatly appreciated

Comment: The issues sounds more like a non-compilable code than a issue with your pipeline. Does your code compile successfully?

Comment: What's the msbuild toolpath in your machine? And what folder the msbuild command comes from, VS IDE or build tools for vs?

Comment: The code does compile successfully. As I said, it is intermittent. In fact it hasn't thrown the error in a day or so

Comment: @A.Thurm Friend, does this issue occurs accidentally when using Jenkins pipeline to call msbuild. I mean does this issue happen when building it locally by msbuild or VS IDE?

Comment: I have not seen this error in a while I am guessing it attributes to Windows updates